# Ошибка при попытке соединения с базой данных в Spring Framework

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, spring

Пишу вебсайт с использованием Spring Framework, при соединении с базой данных получаю кучу ошибок.  Решения в гугле не нашёл.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2023-07-06T11:27:36.896+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.SellAndBuy.SellAndBuyApplication     : Starting SellAndBuyApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 2748 (E:\Projects\SellAndBuy\target\classes started by olehh in E:\Projects\SellAndBuy)
2023-07-06T11:27:36.900+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.SellAndBuy.SellAndBuyApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-06T11:27:36.964+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-07-06T11:27:36.965+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-07-06T11:27:37.604+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-06T11:27:37.627+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-06T11:27:38.253+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-06T11:27:38.264+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-06T11:27:38.264+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2023-07-06T11:27:38.320+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-06T11:27:38.322+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1356 ms
2023-07-06T11:27:38.480+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-06T11:27:38.536+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.5.Final
2023-07-06T11:27:38.539+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-07-06T11:27:38.663+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-06T11:27:38.781+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-07-06T11:27:38.795+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-06T11:27:40.018+03:00 ERROR 2748 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.oleggrug.SellAndBuy.SellAndBuyApplication.main(SellAndBuyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

2023-07-06T11:27:40.038+03:00  WARN 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.oleggrug.SellAndBuy.SellAndBuyApplication.main(SellAndBuyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

2023-07-06T11:27:40.044+03:00 ERROR 2748 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
2023-07-06T11:27:40.046+03:00  WARN 2748 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
2023-07-06T11:27:40.053+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-07-06T11:27:40.073+03:00  INFO 2748 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-06T11:27:40.094+03:00 ERROR 2748 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.oleggrug.SellAndBuy.SellAndBuyApplication.main(SellAndBuyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Буду крайне признателен за помощь в решении.

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Ну вроде вполне вменяемо написано: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

Comment: возможно неправильно заданы параметры для подключения к БД, или диалект: `Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')`